# Datatables multiple column filter and pagination

Tags: jquery, datatables

Does pagination and multi-column filtering work together in DAtaTables?

I've combined two sample sources

[http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html](http://datatables.net/development/pagination)

and

http://datatables.net/development/pagination

I don't get any compile errors.  Pagination will work.  When entering a value in one of the columns to filter records on, it gives a javascript error  TypeError G is null

Each of the sources work independently, but they don't play well together.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The answer is - yes they should do. Please provide a link to a page which shows your combination where it doesn't work.

Comment: We have these two plug-ins working in conjunction perfectly. As Allan stated, we'll need some code.